# Changing CSS class on wizard navigation div

Tags: asp.net, .net, wizard, formwizard, aspwizard

I have a load of wizard controls and I need to slightly modify the html it is spitting out around the navigation. Currently I have the below..

```
<div class="nav">
    <input type="submit" value="Back" class="secondary" id="FinishPreviousButton" name="FinishPreviousButton">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="primary" id="FinishButton" name="FinishButton">
</div>
```

I have added my desired classes to the buttons, primary and secondary, but i cant seem to work out how to change the containing div's class from nav. I've already tried .NavigationStyle.CssClass but that isnt doing the trick.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, NavigationStyle.CssClass was getting overridden. Sorted now.